# Error calling super __init__ in Python

Tags: python

I am having trouble calling the super **init** method, I'm very new to python. Code:

```
class Employee:
    "Our common employee base class"

    empCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        Employee.empCount += 1

    def displayCount(self):
        print "Total number of employees: ", Employee.empCount

    def displayEmployee(self):
        print "Name: %s , Salary: $%d" % (self.name,self.salary)

    def __del__(self):
        print "Class destroyed"
```

Now I also have a class SuperIntern:

```
class SuperIntern(Employee):
    internCount = 0

    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(name, salary)
        SuperIntern.internCount +=1

    def displayNumInterns(self):
        print "We have %d interns" %SuperIntern.internCount


intern2 = SuperIntern("Harry", 22)
```

When I try to create an instance of this class I get the error: super(self.**class**, self).**init**(name, salary), TypeError: must be type, not classobj. I have tried using the class name SuperIntern directly instead of self.**class** and it still throws an error. Could someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, don't use `super(self.__class__, self)`.  It will break if your inheritance tree is more than two classes deep.  You have to actually name the class where the method is defined, i.e., `super(SuperIntern, self)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2, `super` can only be used with new-style classes. `Employee` must extend `object`:

```
class Employee(object):
    # ...
```

This makes `Employee` a new-style class (and `SuperIntern` as well, since it now extends a new-style class).

Comment: Thanks for this. Working now.